# Transpile a bunch of ES7 js files into compatible files

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I have a folder with a bunch of javascript. I want to be able to use recent js syntax (especially await/async). But the target should compatible with most browsers.

Since these javascript files will be used standalone (will be imported in a 3rd party app as plugin), I want to respect these scheme:

- `src/file1.js` ==> `dist/file1.js`
- `src/sub/file2.js` ==> `dist/sub/file2.js`
- ...

each files should be transpiled into a es5 js file.

I'm using gulp 4 as build tool.

How to reach my goal ?

### First try : use babel-gulp:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import babel from 'gulp-babel';

const javascript = () => {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel({
            "presets": [
                ["@babel/preset-env", {
                    "targets": {
                        "browsers": [">0.25%", "not ie 11", "not op_mini all"]
                    }
                }]
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
};
```

The build succeeds, but at runtime, it fails with `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

### Second try, using browserify and @babel/polyfill, inspired from [Browserify + Globs (multiple destination)](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-multiple-destination.md)

Added `require("@babel/polyfill");` at top of my javascript files.

in gulp file:

```
const javascript2 = () => {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.js', {
            read: false
        }) // no need of reading file because browserify does.

    .pipe(tap(function(file) {
            file.contents = browserify(file.path).bundle();
        }))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: true
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
};
```

The build succeed, but the file is not transpiled (async keywords remain) and moreover, the whole babel polyfills are included in the output (and it's quite big) which conflicts with the target app (the app is also redefining startsWith function).

Comment: If your wanting each `.js` file to stand on it's own, then each JS could potentially be large, due to having to embed the polyfill's,.  If on the other hand you don't mind your consumers of your lib's having to load another script first.  Bit like `jquery-ui`, would require `jquery` loaded, the you could load the poly fill from a cdn. -> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.2.5/polyfill.js  Of course make sure you load the correct version, that link is for `7.2.5`

Comment: I only use a very small subset of the polyfills. Maybe there's a way to specify which ones should be included (the docs is not clear for me)

Comment: The whole `polyfill` 7.2.5, minified is only 30k,.  So you could start there, and if you want to make it smaller, I believe you could create a custom polyfill.js with only the polyfill's you require..  Personally I'd worry about getting things to work, than the size ATM.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set up a development environment. I would suggest using webpack instead of gulp, 'cause it's more relevant these days. Here's the guide I used to set one up: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-tutorial/.

Comment: Can webpack respect my goal to have one source file to one dest file ?